# QuickSight Session Token

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I am trying to embed a QuickSight console for a registered user in an iframe. Currently, I am stuck on this error

> Embedding failed because of invalid URL or authorization code. Both of these must be valid and the authorization code must not be expired for embedding to work.

I have the sample code from AWS but can’t seem to get it running. I have everything for this code

```
var quicksightClient = new AmazonQuickSightClient(
                AccessKey,
                SecretKey,
                SessionToken,
                Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
```

except for the Session Token which needs a string and not

```
AWS_STS = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(access_key, secret_key);
token = AWS_STS.GetSessionTokenAsync();
```

as I tried. What is this session token and is it mandatory for QuickSight embedded? AWS has other QuickSight Client constructors like

```
public AmazonQuickSightClient(AWSCredentials credentials);

public AmazonQuickSightClient(AWSCredentials credentials, RegionEndpoint region);

public AmazonQuickSightClient(string awsAccessKeyId, string awsSecretAccessKey);
```

which avoid the session token. When I tried using them I still got the same error.

This is the example class from AWS.

```
using System;
using Amazon.QuickSight.Model;
using Amazon.QuickSight;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace QuickSight
{
    public class GenerateDashboardEmbedUrl
    {
        public string doAll() {
            
            var amazonBase = new AmazonBase();
        var quicksightClient = new AmazonQuickSightClient(
                amazonBase.getAccessKey(),
                amazonBase.getSecretKey(),
               // SessionToken,
                Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            try
            {
                RegisteredUserQuickSightConsoleEmbeddingConfiguration registeredUserQuickSightConsoleEmbeddingConfiguration
                    = new RegisteredUserQuickSightConsoleEmbeddingConfiguration
                    {
                        InitialPath = "/start"
                    };
        RegisteredUserEmbeddingExperienceConfiguration registeredUserEmbeddingExperienceConfiguration
            = new RegisteredUserEmbeddingExperienceConfiguration
            {
                QuickSightConsole = registeredUserQuickSightConsoleEmbeddingConfiguration
            };

         return 
            quicksightClient.GenerateEmbedUrlForRegisteredUserAsync(new GenerateEmbedUrlForRegisteredUserRequest
                    {
                        AwsAccountId = amazonBase.getAccountId(),
                        ExperienceConfiguration = registeredUserEmbeddingExperienceConfiguration,
                        UserArn = MyArn,
                        //AllowedDomains = null,
                        SessionLifetimeInMinutes = 100
                    }).Result.EmbedUrl;
            } catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return ex.Message;
}
        }
    }
}
```

I also gave permissions in IAM for QuickSight with

```
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "quicksight:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share more of your code? Are you using `GenerateEmbedUrlForRegisteredUserAsync`? What are the IAM policies assosciated with the IAM principal e.g. user/role you're using the creds of?

Comment: What is the value of `MyArn`? And can you please use `ex.ToString()` and add the full stack trace to the question?

Comment: MyArn is my aws arn for QS that I got from CloudShell. The only error I get is the one posted and it is from the embedded iframe in the CSHTML.